# Can git tags be reused

Tags: git, git-tag

General use of the word tag implies it can be reused to tag different instances. Can tags be reused in Git?

Comment: Tags can't be reused in Git. What's the scenario that you need a tag assigned to different commits? Maybe you could achieve it with different approaches.

Comment: hmm I don't know a good way to do that. You could rebase and change the commit messages adding a "tag" `[module-123] commit message`, but you will need `push --force` after rebasing OR you could create tags `tagModule.count`, i.e.  `tagModule.1, `tagModule.2` etc. But both solutions don't look good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Git tags](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html) can't be reused. A tag can be [removed](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=282175551) and reassigned.